# Multi modal Distribution

Tags: regression, machine-learning, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

I have dependent monetary variable which is a lognormally distributed , i transformed it into log normally distributed using log function in R , after that mean and median has been very close. Now problem with one independent variable which has multimodal distribution. Do i need to convert this independent variable as log normally distributed as well? If yes how can i do this?

Comment: No. There is no requirement that independent variable being normal distributed.

Comment: thanks @user158565 , but what about scaling? After conversion of dependent variable , independent variable is on different scale. Do i need to convert this multimodal to log as well in order to get more linearity?

Comment: Linear transformation (including scaling) on independent variable is meaningless. Non-linear transformation (including log) is needed if you find or know that there is non-linear relationship between dependent variable and independent variable.

Comment: @user158565 make sense , last question if in my model some variable has linear relationship with dependent variable and some has non linear in that what should we chose?

Comment: Keep the variables with linear relationship as they are; make the suitable transformations on variables with non-linear relationship.

Comment: @user158565 thanks  how can i mark your reply as answered? there is no mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in

Comment: I moved comments to the Answer. Now you can mark the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no requirement that independent variable being normal distributed.

Linear transformation (including scaling) on independent variable is meaningless. Non-linear transformation (including log) is needed if you find or know that there is non-linear relationship between dependent variable and independent variable.

Keep the variables with linear relationship as they are; make the suitable transformations on variables with non-linear relationship.